# How to use rewrite on a subexpression of the current goal

Tags: coq

In coq, is it somehow possible to apply a lemma or hypothesis to a subexpression of the current goal?  For example I would like to apply the fact that plus is commutative in order to swap 3 and 4 in this example.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Plus.

Inductive foobar : nat -> Prop :=
 | foob : forall n:nat, foobar n.

Goal foob (3 + 4) = foob (4 + 3).
Proof.
apply plus_comm. (* or maybe rewrite plus_comm *)
```

gives:

```
Error: Impossible to unify "?199 + ?200 = ?200 + ?199" with
"foob (3 + 4) = foob (4 + 3)".
```

How can I tell coq where exactly in this goal to apply plus_comm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the tactic `simpl` works, but don't ask me why `rewrite plus_comm` or `rewrite (plus_comm 3 4)` doesn't work. `apply` is for implications, not equations.

Comment: It works when I do the following, which is what I actually wanted to prove in the first place.

    Goal foobar (3 + 4) = foobar (4 + 3).
    Proof.
    rewrite plus_comm.
    reflexivity.
    Qed.

I guess rewrite doesn't work on values, only on types.

Comment: `rewrite` works on both (actually types are terms in Coq ;-). The main issue here is that `foob (3+4)` has type `foobar (3+4)` and `foob(4+3)` has type `foobar (4+3)`. Coq can check that both are equal (hence the equality is well-typed), but `rewrite` uses an intermediate form where it is not the case, hence the cryptic error message you get with `rewrite (plus_comm 3 4)`.

Comment: Normally, you should be able to use `pattern` (http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#pattern) for local actions somewhere inside the term.  However, this fails for the same reason @Virgile mentioned.  If that's possible, you can also move to a 'more complete' equality type temporarily (e.g. `JMeq`), do stuff there and then move back.  (I like to think of it as the 'complex number'-analogue of equality.)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, `rewrite` will work if you define the inductive type using a constructor parameter instead of an index:

```
Inductive foobar : Type :=
    | foob (n : nat).
```

Since there is only one constructor for this type, my understanding ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600256/difference-between-type-parameters-and-indices)) is that using an index does not provide any benefit but makes it harder for Coq to pattern-match.

In general, either of the following techniques can achieve the effect of a targeted `rewrite`:

**assert**

```
assert (H: 3 + 4 = 4 + 3). { rewrite <- plus_comm. reflexivity. }
```

**rewrite**

```
(* introduce a new sub-goal where you can prove that the replacement is OK *)
replace (3 + 4) with (4 + 3).
(* Coq orders the new goal last. I think it's clearer to tackle it first *)
Focus 2.
(* do the rewrite *)
rewrite <- plus_comm. reflexivity.
```