# How does the discriminate tactic work?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I was curious about how the `discriminate` tactic works behind the curtain. Therefore I did some experiments.

First a simple Inductive definition:

```
Inductive AB:=A|B.
```

Then a simple lemma which can be proved by the `discriminate` tactic:

```
Lemma l1: A=B -> False.
intro.
discriminate.
Defined.
```

Let's see what the proof looks like:

```
Print l1.

l1 = 
fun H : A = B =>
(fun H0 : False => False_ind False H0)
  (eq_ind A
     (fun e : AB => match e with
                    | A => True
                    | B => False
                    end) I B H)
     : A = B -> False
```

This looks rather complicated and I do not understand what is happening here. Therefore I tried to prove the same lemma more explicitly:

```
Lemma l2: A=B -> False.
apply (fun e:(A=B) => match e with end).
Defined.
```

Let's again see what Coq has made with this:

```
Print l2.

l2 = 
fun e : A = B =>
match
  e as e0 in (_ = a)
  return
    (match a as x return (A = x -> Type) with
     | A => fun _ : A = A => IDProp
     | B => fun _ : A = B => False
     end e0)
with
| eq_refl => idProp
end
     : A = B -> False
```

Now I am totally confused. This is still more complicated.
Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's go over this `l1` term and describe every part of it.

```
l1 : A = B -> False
```

`l1` is an implication, hence by Curry-Howard correspondence it's an abstraction (function):

```
fun H : A = B =>
```

Now we need to construct the body of our abstraction, which must have type `False`. The `discriminate` tactic chooses to implement the body as an application `f x`, where `f = fun H0 : False => False_ind False H0` and it's just a wrapper around the induction principle for `False`, which says that if you have a proof of `False`, you can get a proof of any proposition you want (`False_ind : forall P : Prop, False -> P`):

```
(fun H0 : False => False_ind False H0)
  (eq_ind A
     (fun e : AB => match e with
                    | A => True
                    | B => False
                    end) I B H)
```

If we perform one step of beta-reduction, we'll simplify the above into

```
False_ind False
          (eq_ind A
             (fun e : AB => match e with
                            | A => True
                            | B => False
                           end) I B H)
```

The first argument to `False_ind` is the type of the term we are building. If you were to prove `A = B -> True`, it would have been `False_ind True (eq_ind A ...)`.

By the way, it's easy to see that we can simplify our body further - for `False_ind` to work it needs to be provided with a proof of `False`, but that's exactly what we are trying to construct here! Thus, we can get rid of `False_ind` completely, getting the following:

```
eq_ind A
  (fun e : AB => match e with
                 | A => True
                 | B => False
                 end) I B H
```

`eq_ind` is the induction principle for equality, saying that equals can be substituted for equals:

```
eq_ind : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Prop),
   P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
```

In other words, if one has a proof of `P x`, then for all `y` equal to `x`, `P y` holds.

Now, let's create step-by-step a proof of `False` using `eq_ind` (in the end we should obtain the `eq_ind A (fun e : AB ...)` term).

We start, of course, with `eq_ind`, then we apply it to some `x` - let's use `A` for that purpose. Next, we need the predicate `P`. One important thing to keep in mind while writing `P` down is that we must be able to prove `P x`. This goal is easy to achieve - we are going to use the `True` proposition, which has a trivial proof. Another thing to remember is the proposition we are trying to prove (`False`) - we should be returning it if the input parameter is not `A`.
With all the above the predicate almost writes itself:

```
fun x : AB => match x with
              | A => True
              | B => False
              end
```

We have the first two arguments for `eq_ind` and we need three more: the proof for the branch where `x` is `A`, which is the proof of `True`, i.e. `I`. Some `y`, which will lead us to the proposition we want to get proof of, i.e. `B`, and a proof that `A = B`, which is called `H` at the very beginning of this answer. Stacking these upon each other we get

```
eq_ind A
       (fun x : AB => match x with
                  | A => True
                  | B => False
                  end)
       I
       B
       H
```

And this is exactly what `discriminate` gave us (modulo some wrapping).

Comment: Can one say that the last term above is the shortest way to make "discriminate" explicit ?

Comment: @Cryptostasis I think we can. Alternatively, we can makes some reductions (using `Eval cbv in fun H : A = B => [the above term].`) and arrive at `(fun H : A = B => match H in (_ = y)
                       return match y with
                              | A => True | B => False
                              end
                     with | eq_refl => I end)`.

Comment: Is there a command for printing the _discriminate_ tactic (or any other built-in tactic) ?

Comment: @Cryptostasis What do you mean? Would you like to have access to its source code?

Comment: I mean something like "Print Ltac"

Comment: @Cryptostasis `discriminate` implemented in OCaml, not in Ltac. The standard library "imports" it in [`Coq.Init.Notations`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/7535e268f7706d1dee263fdbafadf920349103db/theories/Init/Notations.v#L93). Following it, we arrive at [`extratactics.ml4`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/d9d8977cf213f0d4b2e8d324c759c23df58ba457/plugins/ltac/extratactics.ml4#L108) and from there we get to [`equality.ml`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/7535e268f7706d1dee263fdbafadf920349103db/tactics/equality.ml#L1061). You might want to start digging further from this point.

Answer (score 8):

Another answer focuses on the discriminate part, I will focus on the manual proof. You tried:

```
Lemma l2: A=B -> False.
apply (fun e:(A=B) => match e with end).
Defined.
```

What should be noted and makes me often uncomfortable using Coq is that Coq accepts ill-defined definitions that it internally rewrites into well-typed terms. This allows to be less verbose, since Coq adds itself some parts. But on the other hand, Coq manipulates a different term than the one we entered.

This is the case for your proof. Naturally, the pattern-matching on `e` should involve the constructor `eq_refl` which is the single constructor of the `eq` type. Here, Coq detects that the equality is not inhabited and thus understands how to modify your code, but what you entered is not a proper pattern-matching.

Two ingredients can help understand what is going on here:

- the definition of `eq`
- the full pattern-matching syntax, with `as`, `in` and `return` terms

First, we can look at the definition of `eq`.

```
Inductive eq {A : Type} (x : A) : A -> Prop :=  eq_refl : x = x.
```

Note that this definition is different from the one that seems more natural (in any case, more symmetric).

```
Inductive eq {A : Type} : A -> A -> Prop :=  eq_refl : forall (x:A), x = x.
```

This is really important that `eq` is defined with the first definition and not the second. In particular, for our problem, what is important is that, in `x = y`, `x` is a parameter while `y` is an index. That is to say, `x` is constant across all the constructors while `y` can be different in each constructor. You have the same difference with the type `Vector.t`. The type of the elements of a vector will not change if you add an element, that's why it is implemented as a parameter. Its size, however, can change, that's why it is implemented as an index.

Now, let us look at the extended pattern-matching syntax. I give here a very brief explanation of what I have understood. Do not hesitate to look at [the reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/extended-pattern-matching.html) for safer information. The `return` clause can help specify a return type that will be different for each branch. That clause can use the variables defined in the `as` and `in` clauses of the pattern-matching, which binds respectively the matched term and the type indices. The `return` clause will both be interpreted in the context of each branch, substituting the variables of `as` and `in` using this context, to type-check the branches one by one, and be used to type the `match` from an external point of view.

Here is a contrived example with an `as` clause:

```
Definition test n :=
  match n as n0 return (match n0 with | 0 => nat | S _ => bool end) with
  | 0 => 17
  | _ => true
  end.
```

Depending on the value of `n`, we are not returning the same type. The type of `test` is `forall n : nat, match n with | 0 => nat | S _ => bool end`. But when Coq can decide in which case of the match we are, it can simplify the type. For example:

```
Definition test2 n : bool := test (S n).
```

Here, Coq knows that, whatever is `n`, `S n` given to `test` will result as something of type `bool`.

For equality, we can do something similar, this time using the `in` clause.

```
Definition test3 (e:A=B) : False :=
  match e in (_ = c) return (match c with | B => False | _ => True end) with
  | eq_refl => I
  end.
```

What's going on here ? Essentially, Coq type-checks separately the branches of the `match` and the `match` itself. In the only branch `eq_refl`, `c` is equal to `A` (because of the definition of `eq_refl` which instantiates the index with the same value as the parameter), therefore we claimed we returned some value of type `True`, here `I`. But when seen from an external point of view, `c` is equal to `B` (because `e` is of type `A=B`), and this time the `return` clause claims that the `match` returns some value of type `False`. We use here the capability of Coq to simplify pattern-matching in types that we have just seen with `test2`. Note that we used `True` in the other cases than `B`, but we don't need `True` in particular. We only need some inhabited type, such that we can return something in the `eq_refl` branch.

Going back to the strange term produced by Coq, the method used by Coq does something similar, but on this example, certainly more complicated. In particular, Coq often uses types `IDProp` inhabited by `idProp` when it needs useless types and terms. They correspond to `True` and `I` used just above.

Finally, I give the [link](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2016-09/msg00032.html) of a discussion on coq-club that really helped me understand how extended pattern-matching is typed in Coq.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24601292/2747511) is (imho) a nice answer, which explains the difference between parameters and indices.