# Induction over relations

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to prove the following toy theorem about the ordering of the naturals:

```
Inductive Le: nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | le_n: forall n, Le n n
  | le_S: forall n m, Le n m -> Le n (S m).

Theorem le_Sn_m: forall n m,
  Le (S n) m -> Le n m.
```

On paper, this is a simple induction on `Le (S n) m`. In particular, the base case of `le_n` is trivial.

In Coq though, beginning my proof with induction gives me the following:

```
Proof.
  intros n m H. induction H.

1 subgoal
n, n0 : nat
______________________________________(1/1)
Le n n0
```

...in which case I am blocked.

How should I proceed instead?

Comment: IMHO this example could sever as an exercise on Coq inductives types and indexes; however, if what you plan to do is to formalize the `<=` relation, this is total overkill and will give you many headaches. I suggest indeed you define your relation as a function `nat -> nat -> bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because Coq treats differently *indices* and *parameters* (see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24600256/2747511) for a very nice explanation).
Your `Le` relation uses indices only, whereas the standard definition makes the first argument a parameter:

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
| le_n : n <= n
| le_S : forall m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m
```

I can recommend reading [this blog post](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrw12/dep-destruct.html) by James Wilcox. Here is a relevant excerpt:

> When Coq performs a case analysis, it first abstracts over all indices. You may have seen this manifest as a loss of information when using destruct on predicates

So you can either (1) change your `Le` relation so it would use a parameter, or (2) use the `remember` tactic as was suggested by @Zimm i48, or (3) use the `dependent induction` tactic mentioned by @Vinz:

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.   (* for `dependent induction` *)

Inductive Le: nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | le_n: forall n, Le n n
  | le_S: forall n m, Le n m -> Le n (S m).
Hint Constructors Le.                  (* so `auto` will work *)

Theorem le_Sn_m: forall n m,
  Le (S n) m -> Le n m.
Proof. intros n m H. dependent induction H; auto. Qed.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a limitation of Coq, when using `induction` on term that are not made only of variables. By doing your induction, Coq forgets about the fact that the first argument was a `S` of some `n`.

You can do the following instead:

```
Theorem le_Sn_m_: forall X m,
  Le X m -> forall n, X = S n -> Le n m.
```

I think there is a `dependent induction` somewhere that could save you this intermediate lemma but I can't recall where.

Comment: @Vinz, if you use emacs and Proof General, then consider looking into the company-coq mode. When you start typing a command, it gives you a pop-up with completions, and you can pick one, press ctrl-h and get the documentation in the technical reference manual. So in this case, just type 'depe' and arrow down to 'dependent induction ident' and press ctrl-h.  The documentation will tell you to include Coq.Program.Equality.  Saves you a trip to the web browser and a mental context switch at least...

Comment: Good to know ! Thanks @larsr

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Vinz suggestion, but without changing the statement you are proving:

```
Proof.
  intros n m H.
  remember (S n) as p.
  induction H.
```

Using the [`remember`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.remember) tactic will introduce an equality in your context which will avoid losing this critical information.