# Try to understand concept of Indexed type family

Tags: coq, type-families

With the following definition:

```
Inductive eq (A : Type) (x : A) : A → Prop := eq refl : (eq x) x

Parameter a b : A.
```

When I consider one of its instance `eq a b`, I read `(eq a)` of type `A -> Prop`.

Then, my question is that how `(eq a) b` can establish the fact that `a` and `b` corresponds to the same object?

The strange thing to me is that we have no information about what does `(eq a)` actually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eq a is a predicate that is only defined (only has the inhabitant eq_refl) if its argument is equal to b, where equality means "up to unification by the typechecker". So a has to be seen by Coq to be the same as b, otherwise Eq a b is equivalent to False.

Answer (score 4):

To add to John's answer, people seem to appreciate the informal description I gave here of how I think intuitively of indexed type families:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601292/553003

I would also add that there is a distinction between the type `(eq a) b` (which is the same as `eq a b`), and a term that has this type.

For instance, you can define:

```
Definition a_weird_type : Type := eq 0 42.
```

Because such a type is just a statement without a proof. You should not be able to define `a_weird_term` that has type `a_weird_type` though, because you will never convince the system that 0 and 42 are actually equal.

Note that there is still a little bit of checking though, so you cannot define:

```
Definition a_weirder_type : Type := eq 42 true. (* Coq will reject this *)
```

Because the `eq` type implicitly carries the type of the elements it compares, and the type system will ensure that the two elements have that type:

```
Check (@eq nat 42 true).
(*                ^^^^ this should have type nat *)

Check (@eq bool 42 true).
(*              ^^ this should have type bool *)

Check (@eq nat 23 42).
(* fine, but not provable *)
```