# Coq: cannot unify inductive types

Tags: arrays, types, coq, unification

I am trying to represent multi-dimensional arrays as restricted functions, and I am having a trouble with defining what seem to be a primitive function.

Here are the definitions:

```
Require Export Fin.
Require Export PeanoNat.

Inductive ispace : nat -> Type :=
  Rect: forall d:nat, ((Fin.t d) -> nat) -> ispace d.

Inductive index : nat -> Type :=
  Idx: forall d: nat, (Fin.t d -> nat) -> index d.

Inductive bound_idx : forall d, index d -> ispace d -> Prop -> Type :=
  RectBoundIdx : forall d f_idx f_shp,
                 bound_idx d (Idx d f_idx) 
                             (Rect d f_shp)
                             (forall i, f_idx i < f_shp i).
Inductive array : 
  forall d (is:ispace d), 
           (forall idx pf, bound_idx d idx is pf -> nat) -> Type :=
  RectArray: forall (d:nat) sh_f val_f, 
             array d (Rect d sh_f) val_f.
```

I define type families for rectangular index-spaces, for indices and for an index that is bounded by a rectangular index-space.  The array type is a function from a restricted index-space to nat.

Now, I am trying to construct an array from such a function:

```
Definition func_to_arr d is (af:forall idx pf,
                             bound_idx d idx is pf -> nat) :=
  match is with
  | Rect d f => RectArray d f af
  end.
```

And Coq tells me:

```
Error:
In environment
d : nat
is : ispace d
af : forall (idx : index d) (pf : Prop), bound_idx d idx is pf -> nat
d0 : nat
f : t d0 -> nat
The term "af" has type "forall (idx : index d) (pf : Prop), bound_idx d idx is pf -> nat"
while it is expected to have type "forall (idx : index d0) (pf : Prop), bound_idx d0 idx (Rect d0 f) pf -> nat"
(cannot unify "index d0" and "index d").
```

So I am wondering, how can I pass this information to the above definition, so that it becomes valid.  Unless I misunderstand something, the type of af contains all the necessary information to reconstruct an array.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very common in dependently-typed programming with Coq. To solve it, people usually use the *convoy pattern* described in [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) by A. Chlipala (MoreDep chapter, IIRC) and mentioned multiple time on Stackoverflow.

Here is how you can define the function.

```
Definition func_to_arr d is (af:forall idx pf, bound_idx d idx is pf -> nat) :=
  match is
  as is'
  in (ispace d1)
  return
    forall af' : forall idx pf, bound_idx d1 idx is' pf -> nat, array d1 is' af'
  with
  | Rect d2 f => fun af' => RectArray d2 f af'
  end af.
```

I'm doing dependent pattern-matching here, basically performing "rewrites" of indices so Coq can see the connections between variables that a human reader ususally takes for granted. You can read about the constructions I used here in [extended pattern matching](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/extended-pattern-matching.html#matching-objects-of-dependent-types) section of the manual.

Incidentally, if you made `d` a *parameter* of your inductive types instead of making it an *index*, you would not need to mess with `d1`, `d2` and the `in (ispace d1)` would not be necessary. If the choice was accidental, then you might want to take a look at the [answer explaining the difference between those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600256/difference-between-type-parameters-and-indices/24601292#24601292).