# Extra type constructor if parameter matches a pattern

Tags: coq

Let's define a type representing sets:

```
Inductive mySet :=
| funSet   : mySet -> mySet -> mySet
| prod     : mySet -> mySet -> mySet.
```

We have two type constructors:

- `funSet A B` - a set of functions from `A` to `B`
- `prod A B`   - a set of pairs `A B`.

I would like to define type representing elements of these sets in the following way

```
Inductive el (X : mySet) :=
  | eval  : forall {Y : mySet}, el (funSet Y X) -> el Y -> el X
  | proj1 : forall {Y : mySet}, el (prod X Y) -> el X
  | proj2 : forall {Y : mySet}, el (prod Y X) -> el X
  | compose : forall {A B C : mySet}, el (funSet A B) -> el (funSet B C) -> el (funSet A C).
```

Where we have a constructor `eval` which can evaluate a function, an element of `funSet X Y` or other constructors `proj1` and `proj2` which extract corresponding element of a pair.

However, the definition of `compose` is not valid as it is. I get an error:

```
Error: Last occurrence of "el" must have "X" as 1st argument in 
 "forall A B C : mySet, el (funSet A B) -> el (funSet B C) -> el (funSet A C)".
```

Ok, that is understandable, but is there a way to enable the constructor `compose` when `X` matches the pattern `funSet A C` ?

I really want to have `compose` as a constructor. Later on, I want to do pattern matching on expression composed of `eval` `proj1` `proj2` `compose`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple enough: make `X` into an index rather than a parameter.

```
Inductive mySet :=
| funSet   : mySet -> mySet -> mySet
| prod     : mySet -> mySet -> mySet.

Inductive el: mySet -> Type :=
  | eval  : forall {X Y : mySet}, el (funSet Y X) -> el Y -> el X
  | proj1 : forall {X Y : mySet}, el (prod X Y) -> el X
  | proj2 : forall {X Y : mySet}, el (prod Y X) -> el X
  | compose : forall {A B C : mySet}, el (funSet A B) -> el (funSet B C) -> el (funSet A C).
```

Intuitively, the difference is that for some inductive type `IndType X`, when `X` is a parameter, each `IndType X` has essentially the same shape. For example, with `list X`, regardless of what `X` is, the elements of the type look like `nil`, `cons a nil`, `cons a (cons b nil)` etc. In contrast, for `el X`, if `X` happens to be some `funSet A C`, it gets some extra constructors of the form `compose f g`. The actual shape of the inductive type depends on what `X` is.

See also:

- [Difference between type parameters and indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600256/difference-between-type-parameters-and-indices)
- [What are the difference between and consequences of using type parameters and type indexes?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20100/what-are-the-difference-between-and-consequences-of-using-type-parameters-and-ty)